# Is this hadith, about paradise being promised to a person for guarding his tongue and private parts, not found in English version of Bukhari?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Is this hadith authentic and what is the explanation behind it?!

حدثنا ‏ ‏محمد بن أبي بكر ‏ ‏حدثنا ‏ ‏عمر بن علي ‏ ‏ح ‏ ‏و حدثني ‏ ‏خليفة ‏ ‏حدثنا ‏ ‏عمر بن علي ‏ ‏حدثنا ‏ ‏أبو حازم ‏ ‏عن ‏ ‏سهل بن سعد الساعدي ‏
‏قال النبي ‏ ‏صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ ‏من توكل لي ما بين رجليه وما بين لحييه توكلت له بالجنة ‏

Muhammad ibn Abi Bakr, Umar ibn Ali narrated and told me Khalifa Umar ibn al-Ali told us told us Abu Hazim from Sahl bin Saad Al-Saadi:
The Prophet peace be upon him said: Whoever entrusts to me what is between his legs and what is between his lips will be granted paradise.

Sahih Bukhari 6309

Comment: What English version of Bukhari are you referring to that's missing it? It's easily found in http://sunnah.com/bukhari/86/37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

As mentioned in the comment above you could find it [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6807) The similar narration is stated in Tirmidhi sharif and regarded as Sahih Hadith.

> Sahl bin Sa'd narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:
> "Whoever guarantees for me what is between his jaws and what is
> between his legs, I shall guarantee Paradise for him."([Tirmidhi](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/36/106))

So It means to guard something which is in between jaws i.e Tongue and to guard which is in between legs i.e Private parts.By improper use of these a person could be a sinner,If a person has not control on his tongue that could lead to sins by backbiting,hurting,lying or causing some mischief ,

> Sufyan bin 'Abdullah Ath-Thaqafi said: I said: "O Messenger of Allah!
> Inform me about a matter that I may hold fast to." He said: 'Say: My
> Lord is Allah, then be steadfast.' I said: "O Messenger of Allah! What
> do you fear most for me?" So he took hold of his tongue and said:
> 'This.'"(Tirmidhi)

Similarly Protecting one's private parts means to protect one self from involving adultery is very important,Allah swt has mentioned punishment for such  in the Quran.

> And those who do not worship any other deity along with Allah, and do
> not unjustly kill any living thing which Allah has forbidden, nor
> commit adultery; and whoever does this will receive punishment.(Quran
> 25:68)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.